# Estimating proportion from aggregate data using regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, beta-regression

I am trying to estimate if a certain product is purchased by certain race(s) more than other.
To do so, we have the following *aggregate* data

| Zip_code | Percentage_of_buyers | Asian_% | Black_% | Hispanic_% | White_% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | 90% | 10% | 5% | 7% | 78% |
| xxxxx | 50% | 5% | 60% | 10% | 25% |

The percentage of buyers is coming from our data/study. The race breakdown is coming from Census data.

What we want to do is to be able to say
x % of black buy this product vs x % of white
using the info above.

Is using linear regression and simply take the coefficients next to each race would be enough?
In this case, does the regression coefficient represent % from that race?
If we want to add more variables, how would we interpret the coefficients
More variables like

| Zip_code | Percentage_of_buyers | Asian_% | Black_% | Low_income_% | High_income_% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxxxx | 90% | 10% | 5% | 80% | 20% |
| xxxxx | 50% | 5% | 60% | 60% | 40% |

What would the coefficients here mean?

I am aware of the ecological fallacy from the first table, would adding more variables like income, education ... etc. adjust for that?

Appreciate any insights and happy to provide more information.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to be able to say from this data.  The way you phrase " x % of black buy this product vs x % of white" makes me think you can get there just from some more descriptive statistics like averages by race. If you actually want a marginal effect (that would not be causal but correlational) between your independent variables (percentage of buyers by each race) on your dependent variable (the percent of people by each race who live in a given zip code?) then regression might be appropriate.

Comment: @NoahHammarlund
Thank you for your reply! Yes, I think I need to be clearer. 
First, we don't have race data for the buyers, so descriptive is not an option here.
Instead, we try to estimate that correlation between % of buyers in each zip code and race breakdown for each zip code. 
Now, I think we agree on regression, is the coefficient next to the race = the proportion of buyers from that race?

Comment: The interpretation of the coefficient X on black race would be something like "an increase of 1 in the % of black people living a zipcode leads to a change of X in the % of buyers in a zip holding all other independent variables constant". This is definitely not a causal effect and the theories of causal inference are vast. Adding additional variables can help in a specific way but you can never include everything. These associations can still be informative but it is good to know the reasons why they might also be biased or misleading if you want to use them for decision making.